How enable antialias in PixiJS v8+
This is the initialization of the application in version 8.
Previously there was a parameter called "antialias".
  await this.app.init({
                background: '#2b344b',
                resizeTo: this.wrapper,
                antialias: true, //in v8 absent (-_-)
                resolution: window.devicePixelRatio || 2,
                autoDensity: true,
            });


I think it's this problem https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/issues/6407
I also added a shadow shader
const circleBg = new Graphics()
circleBg.filters = [new DropShadowFilter()];
circleBg.circle(0, 0, 30);


 "dependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.8",
    "pixi-filters": "^6.0.4",
    "pixi-layers": "^0.3.1",
    "pixi.js": "^8.2.6",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.2.2",
    "stats.js": "^0.17.0",
    "typedi": "^0.10.0"
  },

i think the same problem
Antialias does not work when applying drop shadow filter in pixi.js
